# Select count based on condition (SQL)

Tags: sql

I have a table with x companies and want to add the number of completed projects for the distinct company.

I tried something like this but then I need to put "b.status" in the group by which is not what I want:

```
Select a.company_id, (Select count(b.project_id) where b.status = 'completed')
from a
join b on a.company_id = b.company_id
group by a.company_id
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please mark the question by relevant RDBMS tag and provide the tables structure and sample data

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is *conditional aggregation*:

```sql
SELECT a.company_id, COUNT(CASE WHEN b.status = 'completed' THEN 1 END) AS cnt
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.company_id = b.company_id
GROUP BY a.company_id;
```

Comment: This query does not return companies with no projects

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev Yes it does...counting `NULL` yields zero.  Your answer is unnecessary.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The inner join removes every company from a that has not a single order in b. We don't know if these should also show up.  https://dbfiddle.uk/aNwKaTjF

Comment: If that be a concern, then using a left join should fix it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, my answer a bit different, so I'll leace it here :)

Answer (score 0):

Below one of possible solutions - JOIN tables with additional condition + aggegation:

```
select c.company_id, count(project_id) porjects_completed
from companies c
left join projects p on c.company_id = p.company_id and p.status = 'completed'
group by c.company_id;
```

test it here: https://sqlize.online/sql/mariadb/20422279cada456a1cc832e5f8bfe013/